# No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix

Tags: android, android-studio, build, drawer

I want to create Flowing Drawer for that i Downloaded Application code from GitHub, but while running/executing code i am facing below error

```
No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android
```

Please see below code from build.gradle (App & Module level)

Module Level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
}
```

App Level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 120
    versionName "1.2.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation project(':flowingdrawer-core')
}
```

I want to create Flowing Drawer like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVATi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
```

with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

In Module Level build.gradle file.

In short The solution is upgrad your griddle to 3.1 or higher level to fix No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android issue.